# Сделать сортировку односвязного списка

Tags: c

Здравствуйте нужно сделать сортировку односвязного списка
Моя структура:

```
struct prog {
char name[80];
unsigned int kol;
double time1;
double time2;

struct prog* next;
};
```

Вот мой код делал сортировку относительно переменной kol  от большего к меньшему

```
void zad6(prog* head) {
prog* p1 = head, * p2 = p1;
for (p2 = head; p2->next; p2 = p2->next) {
    for (p1 = head; p1->next; p1 = p1->next) {
        if (p1->kol > p2->kol) {
            iter_swap(p2, p1);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Но ничего не работает в чем ошибка ?

Comment: `iter_swap` - покажите. Без работающей проги никто не поможет.

Comment: Наверное  вы не меняете указатели `next` в предшествующих элементах

Comment: AlexGlebe , iter_swap это вроде тоже самое что и просто swap или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: avp , а как мне исправить ?